# using regex to help me on my calculator c++

Tags: c++, regex, syntax, calculator

I'm doing a c++ calculator and I'm using regex to make syntax.

But I'm having trouble to validate the expression.

Here is my code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    string blah;
    cout << "Expression :\n";
    cin >> blah;
    regex numb("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+");
    regex ope("(\\+|-|/|\\*|\\(|\\))");
    regex exp("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+(\\+|-|/|\\*|\\(|\\))");
    smatch numbMatch;
    smatch opeMatch;
    smatch expMatch;


    if (!regex_search(blah, expMatch, exp)){
        cout << "Invalid expression" << endl;
        return main();
    }
    else{}

    do{
        if (regex_search(blah, numbMatch, numb)){
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < numbMatch.size(); ++j)
                cout << "Number \n" << numbMatch[j] << endl;
            blah = numbMatch.suffix().str();
        }

        if (regex_search(blah, opeMatch, ope)){
            for (unsigned int i = 1; i < opeMatch.size(); ++i){
                cout << "Operator \n" << opeMatch[i] << endl;
                blah = opeMatch.prefix().str() + opeMatch.suffix().str();
            }
        }
    } while (true); {}
}
```

It doesn't work if I put my expression like a4+4. It goes through my first regex and it doesn't return to `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a recursive function is often a bad idea.
Something like this is much better:

```
while (!regex_search(blah, expMatch, exp)){
        cout << "Invalid expression" << endl;
        cout << "Expression :\n";
        cin >> blah;
}
```

Anyway, regex_search:

> Returns whether some sub-sequence in the target sequence (the subject)
>   matches the regular expression rgx (the pattern)

The string "a4+4" match because there is the expression "4+4" inside the string. Try looking the function regex_match with a regular expression like this:

```
regex exp("[-+]?[0-9]*([-+*/][-+]?[0-9]+)*$");
while (!regex_match(blah, expMatch, exp)){
        cout << "Invalid expression" << endl;
        cout << "Expression :\n";
        cin >> blah;
}
```

Also the do..while loop is also an infinite loop. Try at least:

```
} while (!blah.empty());
```